# Lambda runtime exception 'variable ' ' of type ' ' referenced from scope '', but is not defined

Tags: c#, lambda

```
DataMore1 dm1 = null;
DataMore2 dm2 = null;    

var list = session.QueryOver<Data>()
    .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore1, () => dm1, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
    .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore2, () => dm2, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
    .Select(d => 
        new Data ()
        {
            PlantID = d.PlantID,
            AreaID = d.AreaID,
            CellID = d.CellID,
            DeviceID = d.DeviceID,
            StartDateTime = d.StartDateTime,
            DataPoint01 = d.DataPoint01,
            DataMore1 = new List<DataMore1>(new List<DataMore1>
            {
                new DataMore1 { Segment = dm1.Segment, DataPoint101 = dm1.DataPoint101 }
            }),
            DataMore2 = new List<DataMore2>(new List<DataMore2>
            {
                new DataMore2 { Segment = dm2.Segment, DataPoint201 = dm2.DataPoint201 }
            })
        })
    .List<Data>();
```

produces this exception.

```
variable 'd' of type 'FNHSamples.Data' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a _runtime_ error??

Comment: It certainly isn't a compile time error as it compiles fine and breaks at runtime.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're missing an open curly bracket after `d` is defined.
I have added a return as well.

Try the following:

```
DataMore1 dm1 = null;
DataMore2 dm2 = null;    

var list = session.QueryOver<Data>()
    .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore1, () => dm1, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
    .JoinAlias(data => data.DataMore2, () => dm2, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Expression.Eq("Segment", 0))
    .ToList()
    .Select(d => 
        {
            return new Data ()
            {
                PlantID = d.PlantID,
                AreaID = d.AreaID,
                CellID = d.CellID,
                DeviceID = d.DeviceID,
                StartDateTime = d.StartDateTime,
                DataPoint01 = d.DataPoint01,
                DataMore1 = new List<DataMore1>(new List<DataMore1>{new DataMore1 { Segment = dm1.Segment, DataPoint101 = dm1.DataPoint101 }}),
                DataMore2 = new List<DataMore2>(new List<DataMore2>{new DataMore2 { Segment = dm2.Segment, DataPoint201 = dm2.DataPoint201 }})
            };
        })
        .List<Data>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. This however generates a compile time error. "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree" ... now researching this error...

Comment: See my edit, I have added a `ToList()` before the `Select` to force the query to execute before the transform.

Comment: Excellent! Now I'm onto why dm1 and dm2 are null :) Thanks for getting me over the first hurdle.

Comment: This in no way is an acceptable answer. The dm1 and dm2 are null obviouslby because they are resolved AFTER the query itself. Downvote